# How do I control a servo with python through an Arduino

Tags: serial, python

I'm trying to make it so I can control 2 servos with data that I get from a python script that tracks my face.

I have found 2 libraries that do this:pySerial and pyfirmata.

Is one superior to the other one, are there more libraries, or should approach things differently.

Comment: They're different things: one is a specific interface to Arduino Firmata, one is a generic serial port library. "Superior" depends on context, usage, etc. Either would work perfectly fine, each would require a different approach.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I'd say pyFirmata can work but controling servos ... NOPE!
use pyserial and add the code

Comment: Did you see Dave Newton's comment below the question?

Comment: no but thanks i needed it